# Mending broken solar cells

Tags: solar-cell, repair

Which is the best way to connect broken pieces of solar cell to equal 1 solar cell? Below are 3 configurations of how I might use solder to build a cell. Does the configuration make a difference?

[image]

Comment: mending broken glass?  PV's are current sources with Voc. What are the parameters of each if not same then put parallel, P, if matched then series ,S is ok ... or matrix xSyP of matched current parallel groups in series.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 all are parallel

Comment: ensure each pc. has no shorts.. measure Voc with bright light.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 like using electrical conducting tape instead of solder?

Comment: first probe under light, connecting is a problem , I cant see, maybe 99% silver epoxy.. probably not fixable.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 all of these would be ok then?  if I connect a to b to c in series it should make 1.5 volts the same if I connect a to a to a?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I would take this to chat but I can't... I understand to inspect each piece for cracks using a light. I did that but I just want to make sure there is no difference in efficiency and redundancy.

Comment: Since they are of unequal size and I assume you will not be adding bypass diodes, series connection is almost out of the question unless just a demonstration on the bench for students or similar. With no short, paralleling them should work fine. Also +1 for very interesting question and included "circuit diaram" from the start.

Comment: Buy a new one..

Comment: @Andyaka I can build them at 10 cents a watt this way.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm poor

Comment: Please come and visit me in your private jet when you make it big LOL. How many folk stop me in the street saying they are poor when they are not.

Comment: They already have a type of panel made of bits of solar. Just doing this to save on power for the house.

Comment: commercial volume cost is about $0.4/W and broken ones should be < 10% so 4 cents a watt. You are paying too much

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I will look harder

Comment: If your interconnects are low resistance, it should not matter which paralell configuration you go for, but I like variant A. Do you plan on running multiple such configuration in series?

Comment: @winny yes and I should parallel  it from the center piece on (A) from what you are saying?

Comment: Since the total area will differ between your parallel branches, your anti-shading diodes will need to cover any current difference between your series elements. Try to match the area/short circuit current capability of each series element to minimize this effect. I would go for A to have the largest piece in the center.

Answer (score 1):

First the easy answer then the difficult one.

1. Easy answer buy very low cost cells from China. Less than $1 us including shipping to my house in the US. Here's a [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=52806&initiative_id=AS_20190418152247&SearchText=solar+cell)
2. Tough Answer: To connect the pieces you need to..... find which of the electrodes are P and N junctions. This is not easy with pieces. If you can figure it out you need to connect all the wire traces of the P junctions and all the wire junctions of the N junctions. 
   Here's a [link](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/chat/sunpower-maxeon-solar-cell-discussion/) to a picture of the back of a cell with positive and negative terminals.

Not sure this is clear, but it's very difficult after the cells are broken.